# Execute code in seperate class when boolean changes

Tags: java, javafx

So, I'm creating a snakes and ladders game in javafx, that asks a question when the player lands on a ladder or snake, and decides whether to go up the ladder/down the snake or not based on whether the answer is correct or not.

I have a Question class that creates a new window and displays the question, as well as a place to answer it, and a 'correct' boolean value that I am hoping to essentially, return to the main class, when the button is clicked.

Since EventHandlers cannot directly return values, I am hoping to say 'if the value of this 'correct' variable has changed, execute a getter method to get and store the value' but I don't know how to create a listener to check if the value has changed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Post some code, so people can point out where to put the listener code.

Comment: What type of listener you want?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
public class Question {

    public enum State {UNANSWERED, CORRECT, INCORRECT} 

    private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<State> state 
        = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(State.UNANSWERED);

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<State> stateProperty() {
        return state.getReadOnlyProperty() ;
    }

    public final State getState() {
        return stateProperty().get();
    }

    private Button button ;

    public Question() {
        // ...
        button = new Button(...);
        button.setOnAction( event -> {
            if (checkAnswer()) {
               state.set(State.CORRECT);
            } else {
               state.set(State.INCORRECT);
            }
        });
        // etc..

    }

    public void showWindow() {
        // display window with question and controls, etc...
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
Question question = new Question();
question.stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
    if (state == Question.State.CORRECT) { /* ...*/}
    else if (state == Question.State.INCORRECT) { /* ... */}
});
question.showWindow();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type of listener you want but I found this for javafx changelistener at http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm. This might help you get started

```
package propertydemo;

import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  Bill electricBill = new Bill();

   electricBill.amountDueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener(){
    @Override public void changed(ObservableValue o,Object oldVal, 
             Object newVal){
         System.out.println("Electric bill has changed!");
    }
  });

  electricBill.setAmountDue(100.00);

}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a great API built for Dialogs. It's going to become part of the official JavaFX API, but for now you can use the separate library: 
[Dialogs](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/)
Confirmation Dialog is probably the one you're looking for.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

To whoever had edited my answer: Do you realize latest Official Java Version is Update 31, so Update 40 is not part of the official API yet?